# Inserting page nr. in word doc and import the data to excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, office-automation

I would like to import all the data from a word doc into excel but before that I would like to add the page numbers in the word doc.

```
Sub ImportWord()
    'UpdatebyExtendoffice20190530
    Dim xObjDoc As Object
    Dim xWdApp As Object    
    Dim xWdName As Variant    
    Dim xWb As Workbook    
    Dim xWs As Worksheet    
    Dim xName As String    
    Dim xPC, xRPP
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    xWdName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word file(*.doc;*.docx) ,*.doc;*.docx", , "Kutools - Please select")    
    If xWdName = False Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook    
    Set xWs = xWb.Worksheets.Add    
    Set xWdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    xWdApp.ScreenUpdating = True    
    xWdApp.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    Set xObjDoc = xWdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=xWdName, ReadOnly:=True)
    xObjDoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = 1    
    xObjDoc.Activate
    xPC = xObjDoc.Paragraphs.Count    
    Set xRPP = xObjDoc.Range(Start:=xObjDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Start, End:=xObjDoc.Paragraphs(xPC).Range.End)    
    xRPP.Select
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    xWdApp.Selection.Copy    
    xName = xObjDoc.Name    
    xName = Replace(xName, ":", "_")    
    xName = Replace(xName, "\", "_")    
    xName = Replace(xName, "/", "_")    
    xName = Replace(xName, "?", "_")    
    xName = Replace(xName, "*", "_")    
    xName = Replace(xName, "[", "_")    
    xName = Replace(xName, "]", "_")
    
    If Len(xName) > 31 Then    
        xName = Left(xName, 31)    
    End If
    
    xWs.Name = xName    
    xWs.Range("A1").Select
    xWs.Paste
    
    'If something goes wrong, go to the errorhandler
    On Error GoTo ERRORHANDLER
    'Checks the document for excessive spaces between words
    
    xObjDoc.Close    
    Set xObjDoc = Nothing    
    xWdApp.DisplayAlerts = True    
    xWdApp.ScreenUpdating = True    
    xWdApp.Quit (wdDoNotSaveChanges)    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you want to import the data from Word into Excel, why do you want the page number in the Word doc? What is the problem with the code you're using?

Comment: so the macro imports serial letters with different things (amounts, wiring informations etc. and the page nr. would help me to group the imported data because each client has 3 pages.

Comment: Adding the page #s to the page header or footer (which is how they are usually applied), won't do what you want, and adding them to the document body will mess up the document pagination.